# Managing Text and Image in css

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style="padding: 40px;background-color: skyblue">
        <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left">
            <h2>Given Way</h2>
            <p>
                Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet liquorice chocolate. Danish gingerbread chupa chups I love brownie brownie gummi bears sesame snaps. 
                Muffin cupcake sugar plum tiramisu sweet I love I love marshmallow tootsie roll. Danish biscuit marzipan pastry croissant ice cream sweet roll.
                 Gummies I love chupa chups marzipan jujubes. Apple pie ice cream jujubes. Candy lemon drops candy canes pastry oat cake pastry. 
                Tootsie roll dessert ice cream halvah cheesecake dessert.</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; float:right">
           <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDJ9l0WKu3DYn_vUf4Cw93mV5vpMsHRhoA7tuCPVnq_tT1l1XD" width="65px" height="65px" alt="Client1"> 
         </div>  
     </div>
```

This code was supposed to make the paragraph contents in the left and the image to the right, but it's not doing so.
What is the reason that the native div is not supported by the css blocks?

Answer (score 1):

use display: flex

```html
<div style="padding: 40px;background-color: skyblue;display: flex;">
  <div style="">
    <h2>Given Way</h2>
    <p>
      Cupcake Ipsum dolor sit amet liquorice chocolate. Danish gingerbread chupa chups I love brownie brownie gummi bears sesame snaps. Muffin cupcake sugar plum tiramisu sweet I love I love marshmallow tootsie roll. Danish biscuit marzipan pastry croissant
      ice cream sweet roll. Gummies I love chupa chups marzipan jujubes. Apple pie ice cream jujubes. Candy lemon drops candy canes pastry oat cake pastry. Tootsie roll dessert ice cream halvah cheesecake dessert.</p>
  </div>
  <div style="">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDJ9l0WKu3DYn_vUf4Cw93mV5vpMsHRhoA7tuCPVnq_tT1l1XD" width="65px" height="65px" alt="Client1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please expand on "why" this fixes his issue.

Answer (score 0):

"What is the reason that the native div is not supported by the css blocks?"

It appears your question is looking for understanding and not just a quick fix answer so...

You are not enforcing width on the container div. Paragraphs are block level elements. They will take up all the given space they can of the containing parent element (your div). In turn divs will take up all given space unless otherwise confined also block-level. So it is taking up the entire line before the next element is processed and display. Then the next element floats to the right under the block element.

So then comes decorating your divs with inline block. All this is telling the browser to do is to calculate its width based upon the child elements. Since your child element is a block level element with no enforced width, it gives no impact in terms of width containment.

If you were to either add spacial dimeninsions to your containing div then it would only take thatamount of space and allow your float element to take over the rest.

OR

If you were to move your float div above the div containing your paragraph then the float dive would take up X amount of space to render and your block element would take up the rest of the space on the same line.

I hope this helps for your understanding of why.

Answer (score 0):

you simply have to focus on combination of two point in this type(float bases) of design.

First, is there any width given to both element(left & right) 
Second, what is the length of the content (left & right)

if first element is float left and content of the element width is shorter than parent width, and also content of right element width with float right is also equal or smaller than difference between first element width  and parent width or vice versa, in this case the both element are set side to side (left, right).

but is any of one has more width than difference it will be display as (top, down) way.

in your case left side content length is more than parent element and also not restricted by any width, so it will grow to the edge of the parent element, so right side image is not getting required space to fit.

hope you can understand.